# Intercept and Edit packet using SharpPcap

Tags: c#, sharppcap

I've looked and can't see to find anything on this.

So I have a pc bridged though my main pc, how would I intercept and edit a packet (that i know is going to my other pc) from my main pc? I know how to intercept it, but i can't find anything on editing it.

My current code is:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Retrieve all capture devices
    var devices = CaptureDeviceList.New();

    var device = devices.FirstOrDefault(dev => dev.Description.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("intel(r)"));

    // check device isn't null
    if (device == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();


    while(true)
    {
        // open device
        device.Open();

        var capture = device.GetNextPacket();
        if (capture == null || capture.Data == null)
            continue;

        var packet = PacketDotNet.Packet.ParsePacket(capture.LinkLayerType, capture.Data);
        var asciiz = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(capture.Data);


        if (asciiz.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("xeraxic"))
        {
            asciiz = asciiz.Replace("<view>1</view>",
                                    "<view>2</view>");

            packet.PayloadPacket.PayloadPacket.PayloadData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(asciiz);
            Console.WriteLine("Modified Packet, fingers crossed");
        }

        // close device
        device.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any updates on the solution?

Comment: Bumping old thread :)